# how can i fix how this looks like in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

just started coding a website, so there is not much code to go through but I am having an issue with how my header is aligning.
if you view  [this page](http://samvella.co.uk/raffleit/) in internet explorer and chrome you will notice that the login box is out of place in chrome.

here is my style sheet:

```
    body {

}


.header {
background: url(img/header-bg.png) repeat-x;
}
a {}
.header_links_left {
font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration:none;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-right:30px;
top:3px;
}
.header_links_right {
font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration:none;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:5px;
float: right;
top:3px;
}
.align_right{
right:0px;
position:fixed;
}
h1{}
.header1{
font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
font-size:40px;
padding-top:-3px;
}
```

if you could let me know what is causing this that would be great,thanks.

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: no , how would i go about implementing this?

Comment: See [**Here**](http://bit.ly/1FBAsNA)

Comment: Exactly! Standard margins and paddings vary with different browsers and versions. CSS Reset would explicitly overwrite those values so they will be the same across browsers.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've never seen that website ("Let me Google it for you").. Brilliant!

Comment: I have now added that to the start of my CSS file, but it still appears that chrome is adding in an extra line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this css code in your corresponding line. It would be show your expected output.

style.css at 10 number line

```
.header_links_left {
font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-right: 30px;
float: left;
}
```

style.css at 35 number line

```
.header1 {
    font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: One suggestion to you. The mark up have not enough div tag to style this page. you have to learn first how to do html code properly.

Comment: what was the issue, i did not have a float left ? also one other thing, as you can now see, my page content has gone up to the top. is there an easy way of fixing this, or will i have to put it inside a div and make it a certain width?

Answer (score 0):

adding a clearfix fixes the issue youre having.

```
.clearfix {
    display: table;
    clear:both;
    content: " ";
}
```

You can add the class to the body tag.

Also I recommend you adding a CSS reset. Or you can use normalize.css